# JDBC Connector with Tomcat6 and CentOS5?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, tomcat6, mysql-connector, centos5

I've got two servers, one with `CentOS` and the other with `Debian`.

In Debian I've installed tomcat6 with the last MySQL in Lenny. I only downloaded the MySQL JDBC Driver and drop it in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. It worked perfectly.

Now, in CentOS5, I want to do the same but It doesn't work.

I've installed Tomcat6 (it's working) and mysql-server (it's working too).

I've tried with the same `/lib` folder and nothing (of course I've got the same `JDK`, and the same Tomcat version).

The error always is the same:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

It's like it doesn't find the mysql connector, but It's almost in it place.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

Before of put manually the connector in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` I installed from yum the `mysql-connector-java` package.

I've deleted from `/usr/share/java/` the bin, restarted `tomcat`, and worked!.

Thanks all!